# Cypress intercept - No request ever occurred

Tags: cypress

On clicking a checkbox, a GET request will get triggered in my application.

I am trying to validate this with cypress but it throws '`Timed out retrying after 30000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 30000ms for the 1st request to the route: getGridWind10M. No request ever occurred.`'

**My code:**

```
cy.intercept("GET", "v1/kml/F20210903120000/Wind10M?view=grid*").as('getGridWind10M');
cy.get('[data-test="ckbx-w10m"]')
    .check({ force: true }) 
    .should("be.checked"); 
cy.wait('@getGridWind10M').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)
```

**Actual Endpoint:**

```
https://domain/path/api/v1/kml/F20210903120000/Wind50M?view=grid&time=2021-09-03T14:00:00.000Z&z=3&x=5&y=4
```

**Test Log:**

[image]

[image]

I have tried the following with no luck. Someone please help me to find out where and what am I missing here as the request in successfully completed as shown in the image?

```
cy.intercept("GET", "*/F20210903120000/Wind10M?view=grid*").as('getGridWind10M');
cy.intercept("GET", "*F20210903120000/Wind10M?view=grid&*").as('getGridWind10M');
cy.intercept("GET", "*F20210903120000/Wind10M?view=grid*").as('getGridWind10M');
cy.intercept("GET", "/F20210903120000/Wind10M?view=grid*").as('getGridWind10M');
```

Comment: Instead using the partial URL, have you tried using the entire url `https://domain/path/api/v1/kml/F20210903120000/Wind50M?view=grid&time=2021-09-03T14:00:00.000Z&z=3&x=5&y=4
` ?

Comment: Have you tried using something closer to what is in the Pattern matching example (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Pattern-Matching)? Something like `**/F2021...00/Wind10M*`?

Comment: Thank you both. I missed the two * in the front and your comment helped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can catch it with a leading `**` meaning multiple preceding parts, and a trailing `?*` meaning has some search params.

```js
const url = "**/v1/kml/F20210903120000/Wind10M?*"
cy.intercept('GET',url, {}).as('getGridWind10M')    // stubbing here
cy.get('checkbox').check()
cy.wait('@getGridWind10M')
```

I note there is a difference in the actual endpoint `Wind50M` and the intercepted endpoint `Wind10M`, probably a typo?

This also works if you are wilcarding middle path segments

```js
const url =  "**/v1/kml/*/Wind10M?*"
```